# more elegant way to create object

Tags: javascript

```
if (currentName === 'WORK') {
    dictionary = {
        currentName: 'PLAY',
        left: { timer: !this.state.timer },
        right: { timer: this.state.timer }
    }
} else {
    dictionary = {
        currentName: 'WORK',
        left: { timer: this.state.timer },
        right: { timer: !this.state.timer }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant / compact way to create this object?

Comment: I guess you could put `(currentName === 'WORK')` in a boolean variable, e.g. `isWork` and then define the object properties with ternary operators: `left: { timer: isWork ? !this.state.timer : this.state.timer }`, though that might hurt readability. Personally, I think sometimes more verbose code is better for human consumption, and for the computer it really makes no difference.

Comment: excellent!, thank you. I should have thought of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways you could do this with a ternary

```
dictionary = (currentName === 'WORK') 
    ? {  
        currentName: "PLAY",
        left: { timer: !this.state.timer },
        right: { timer: this.state.timer }
    } 
    : {
        currentName: 'WORK',
        left: { timer: this.state.timer },
        right: { timer: !this.state.timer }
    };
```

or

```
dictionary = {
    currentName: (currentName === 'WORK') ? 'PLAY' : 'WORK',
    left: { timer: (currentName === 'WORK') ? !this.state.timer : this.state.timer },
    right: { timer: (currentName === 'WORK') ? this.state.timer : !this.state.timer }
}
```

My preference would be the first one if you're wanting to avoid creating a variable to store the boolean, and its less repetitive. It just doesn't really save much compared to the if/else block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function for getting a boolean value, depending on another boolean value and a flag for the check.

```
function trueFalse(b, v) {
    return b ? v : !v;
}

var isWork = currentName === 'WORK',
    dictionary = {
        currentName: isWork ? 'PLAY' : 'WORK',
        left: { timer: trueFalse(isWork, !this.state.timer) },
        right: { timer: trueFalse(isWork, this.state.timer) }
    };
```